# Is there any overlap between Blow (2001) and American Made (2017)?

Tags: plot-explanation, blow, american-made

Both [*Blow* (2001)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0221027/) and [*American Made* (2017)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3532216/) deal with US citizens smuggling large quantities of heroin/cocaine into the US for Pablo Escobar.  Granted, the Escobar in Blow appears to be older and more entrenched than the Escobar in American Made (which is completely screwed because Blow supposedly took place *before* American Made...), but was there any overlap in terms of other players, or even Jung/Seal?

Comment: Are you asking if there was overlap in the real backstories of those films or even inside the films' stories (or both?)?

Comment: Both.  Or either.  I could swear there was a scene in American Made that alluded to Blow, but that couldn't be right because of the timeline.